# Importance of the Klee-Minty Cube in Optimization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, computational-complexity, constraints, simplex-method

Has anyone ever heard of the **Klee-Minty Cube** in Optimization?

[image]

Supposedly, the Klee-Minty Cube shows the "flaws" of the Dantzig's Simplex Algorithm. Supposedly, Dantzig's Simplex Algorithm is unable to optimize (i.e. find optimal values in the feasible ranges given some function and constraints) the Klee-Minty Cube in polynomial time, thus showing the "worst case" of the Simplex Algorithm.

**My Question:** Does anyone know why Dantzig's Simplex Algorithm struggles to optimize the Klee-Minty Cube? What kind of obstacles does the Klee-Minty Cube present, such that the Simplex Algorithm is unable to optimize this problem in polynomial time?

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klee%E2%80%93Minty_cube

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: The text says that the Klee-Minty Cube problem is so formulated, that the Danzig's algorithm actually looks to all nodes before finding the right one, i.e. it becomes a full combinatorial problem. If you want to check it by yourself, then program it and then use Debugger to observe, that it behaves like that.

Answer (score 1):

The Simplex Method pivoting rule that Victor Klee and George Minty used is the one that’s most used in practice: taking most positive improving column and using the minimum ratio test. But, because of this approach, others in the field have speculated that this rendition of the Simplex Algorithm only really considers local optimal solutions of each basis leading up to the global optimal basis, and in the *worst case* this could mean taking a long path to the global optimal solution because it doesn’t consider the global shape of the polytope. In other words, a large portion of reaching the global solution in the least amount pivots requires understanding how much the shape of the cube influences pivots. When improving pivots are done randomly in the Simplex Method, it is shown to take [quadratically more pivots than it needs to on average](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/365741). However, an interesting tangent is this: not only does the Simplex algorithm struggle with this cube, [but also interior-point algorithms](http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/%7Edeza/mp2008.pdf).

In practice, because a lot of abstracted problems are so specialized and well-defined that such theoretical issues like this one *usually* don’t occur.

[A recent development](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10097.pdf) using Fabio Vitor’s and Todd Eastman [Double-Pivot Simplex Method](https://digitalcommons.unomaha.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1069&context=mathfacpub) on a few special cases of Klee-Minty cube found that it solved it in much better time than the original single-pivot variant by George Dantzig. Though, again this is due to the pivoting rule they chose for the Double-Pivot Simplex algorithm, further showing that the best-fitting pivoting rule for the problem matters.

[Here is a review of the original Klee-Minty paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=332165) that summarizes it, and it’s impact, of the Klee-Minty cube.